# Why did Pandas stopped parsing mm/dd/yyyy date format?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

Pandas used to parse `datetime` strings in indexing and slicing for convince, however, it seems that it stopped parsing `mm/dd/yyyy` as a date format.

The following code examples all return an `error parsing datetime string`:

Case 1:

```
import pandas as pd
#to_datetime method
pd.to_datetime(['05/05/2017', '11/13/2017'])
```

Case 2:

```
#date_range
longer_ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000),
                      index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
```

Case 3:

```
#Slicing a Series
from datetime import datetime
dates = [datetime(2011, 1, 2), datetime(2011, 1, 5)]
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(2), index=dates)
ts['01/05/2011']
```

I know I can use `yyyy-mm-dd` or I can even use `parse()` from `dateutil.parser`.

BTW, Wes McKinney uses this date format a number of times in his book on Pandas.

Why did they stopped supporting it?

Comment: I can't reproduce. `pd.to_datetime(['05/05/2017', '11/13/2017'])` works fine for me.

Comment: I am using Pandas 0.17.1 on Python 3.6.4. Does the slicing works for you as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) you can see that there is an argument:

> format : string, default None. strftime to parse time, eg “%d/%m/%Y”, note that “%f” will parse all the way up to nanoseconds.

This works fine, for example:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(['05/05/2017', '11/13/2017'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
DatetimeIndex(['2017-05-05', '2017-11-13'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Please note you have an extra space in `'11/ 13/2017'`.

Note that you can use this with `date_range` also:

```
pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('05/03/2017'), periods=200)
```

Comment: This does work in the case of `to_datetime`, however, it can't be used for the slicing nor `date_range`. I know how to get around it, but it is such an inconvenience.

Comment: @iDrwish Hey, note that you can use `to_datetime` inside `date_range`, but, yeah, this involves more typing.

Comment: `pd.DatetimeIndex` does accept `mm/dd/yyyy` format, a bit inconsistent.